# Who should own exim4 under debian?

Tags: exim, debian-squeeze

Installed debian from DVD.  And now I see exim4 is running owned by UID 107.  There is no user 107 in my /etc/passwd.

Same problem on another system (owned by UID 101), so I suspect this is a debian problem...?

Running squeeze on both.

So under debian, who should own the mail system?

This is what I have installed:

```
# dpkg -l | grep exim
ii  exim4                              4.72-6+squeeze2              metapackage to ease Exim MTA (v4) installation
ii  exim4-base                         4.72-6+squeeze2              support files for all Exim MTA (v4) packages
ii  exim4-config                       4.72-6+squeeze2              configuration for the Exim MTA (v4)
ii  exim4-daemon-light                 4.72-6+squeeze2              lightweight Exim MTA (v4) daemon
```

The binary itself is owned by root:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 758852 May 12  2011 /usr/sbin/exim4
```

Comment: On closer examination, it appears there is a user 101...I think the problem is that its name is Debian-exim, and that column in ps output is not wide enough to show it.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the ps utility is only displaying the uid because the username is too long to fit in the column.  It would rather show you a uid than a chopped username.

In the future, you can verify that the uid actually is associated with an existing system user by using this commandline:

```
[todd@tlyons ~]$ getent passwd 125
Debian-exim:x:125:134::/var/spool/exim4:/bin/false
```